# Unable to delete a dictionary key inside a json by using the del function. getting a TypeError

Tags: python, json, dictionary, del

Code shorten for this example, I'm iterating through it as if it had multiple keys.

```
string = '''
{
    "people":
    {
        "a":
        {
            "parent":
            {
                "father": "x"
            }
        }
    }
}
'''

data = json.loads(string)
```

I make sure that my conditional is working, it outputs "**ok**", so it's fine.

```
for name in data["people"].values():
    if name["parent"]["father"] == "x":
        print("ok")
```

Then I modify the code above to delete that key and I get the following error:

**TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'**

```
for name in data["people"].values():
    if name["parent"]["father"] == "x":
        del data["people"][name]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use `name` as a key, but `name` is actually a dictionary, not a string. Use `.items()` to get both the name and the contents:

```
for name, contents in data["people"].items():
    if contents["parent"]["father"] == "x":
        del data["people"][name]
```

However, note that this will not work either. You can't change the size of a dictionary while iterating it. You can force `.items()` to fully consume by calling `list` or similar on it:

```
for name, contents in list(data["people"].items()):
    if contents["parent"]["father"] == "x":
        del data["people"][name]
```

In the end, `data` will just be `{'people': {}}`, which I believe is what you want.

Comment: Thank you so much, it took me a while to understand why the list method was working (I'm so dumb), then I finally understood! but honestly I still can't comprehend the difference between **items()** and **values()**, time to do some google search :)

Comment: @Jsh0s It's quite simple in reality. There are three main dictionary iteration functions: `keys`, `values`, and `items`. `keys` iterates over the keys, `values` iterates over the values, and `items` iterates over tuples, with the first element being the key and the second being the corresponding value.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import json
string = '''
{
    "people":
    {
        "a":
        {
            "parent":
            {
                "father": "x"
            }
        }
    }
}
'''

data = json.loads(string)
l = []

for key, values in data["people"].items():
    if values["parent"]["father"] == "x":
        l.append(key)

for x in l:
    data["people"].pop(x)

print(data)
```

Comment: Im glad I can assist